# shlex: Escaping quotes in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, shlex

I want to split the ascii text

```
1 'K\^o, Suk\'e'
```

which is printed as the Python string

```
line = "1 'K\\^o, Suk\\'e'\n"
```

into

```
['1', 'K\\^o, Suk\\'e']
```

`shlex.split(line)` doesn't work, giving a `ValueError("No closing quotation")`.

I tried adding to `wordchars` as follows:

```
>>> lexer = shlex.shlex(line)
>>> lexer.wordchars += "\\'"
>>> list(lexer)
['1', "'K\\", '^', 'o', ',', "Suk\\'e'"]
```

but again this is not my intention.

Without the quote, everything works as expected:

```
>>> line2= "1 'K\\^o, Suk\\e'\n"
>>> shlex.split(line2)
['1', 'K\\^o, Suk\\e']
```

How can this be fixed?

Edit: The closest I've come is:

```
>>> lexer = shlex.shlex(line)
>>> lexer.wordchars += "\\'"
>>> lexer.wordchars += " "
>>> lexer.wordchars += "\\^"
>>> lexer.wordchars += ","
>>> list(lexer)
['1', "'K\\^o,", "Suk\\'e'"]
```

which is still not right.

Edit: The example string is somewhat misleading. It should also be able to split, say

```
>>> l1 = "C12 H2 'Hello friend'"
```

`shlex` gets `l1` no problem.

Comment: Why would it split on the first space, but not the second one?

Comment: @VasiliSyrakis: Because the second one is inside single quotes.

Comment: @Aquiles: The text in my ascii file is `1 'K\^o, Suk\'e'`. When this is loaded using `f.readlines()`, it is printed as `"1 'K\\^o, Suk\\'e'\n"`. Hopefully this clarifies my meaning.

Comment: Lol, true... my bad... I was thinking in single quote strings... Sorry about that

Comment: This example is also invalid python syntax: `l2 = "1 8.52 H22 '\''`

Comment: @HåkenLid: Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use posix mode and `escapedquotes` to `'"` instead of just `"`

```
>>> line = "1 'K\\^o, Suk\\'e'\n"
>>> lexer = shlex.shlex(line, posix=True)
>>> lexer.escapedquotes = "'\""
>>> list(lexer)
['1', "K\\^o, Suk'e"]
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be simpler to use a regex for the split. This one will split into the first token before any whitespace, followed by the rest of the string.

```
re.match('(\S+)\s+(.*)', line).groups()
```

Comment: No, the only assumption I have it that it's ascii. I might still be able to use your approach, though . . .

Comment: See my edited answer for a more general token split.

Comment: This is a very nice regex, but fails on `line = "C1 C2 C3"`, which `shlex.split` handles nicely.